# Android App blanking image after Recents button

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, onresume, onpause

I have built an Android app using Xamarin and Visual Studio.

In OnResume, I load a bitmap from a resource, create a canvas from it, update the canvas with some text, and set an ImageView to the bitmap.
This works fine, and displays the bitmap with the extra text.
However, if I press the Square button to display the list of recent apps, then select the app again, it shows the bitmap, but without the text I wrote.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you really need to do it in `onResume` ? its not really efficient

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: I chose OnResume as I wanted it to redraw the bitmap if the screen was turned round. I'm new to this, is there a better place for it?